# How to correct decompiled output with `in_stack_` (ppc BE)?

Tags: decompilation, ghidra, mach-o, powerpc

So I have something like:

```
                     *************************************************************
                     * SYS_DRAW_BATCH_RUNS_DATA::Set(matrix4 const*, RECTF con  ..
                     *************************************************************
                     undefined  __thiscall  SYS_DRAW_BATCH_RUNS_DATA_Set (void 
     undefined         r3:1           <RETURN>
     void *            r3:4 (auto)    this
     matrix4 *         r4:4           param_1
     RECTF *           r5:4           param_2
     SYS_DRAW_QUALI    r6:4           param_3
     SYS_DRAW_RUN *    r7:4           param_4
     uint              r8:4           param_5
     SYS_DRAW_MATER    r9:4           param_6
     uint              r10:4          param_7
     astruct_952       Stack[0x38]:32 param_8                                 XREF[1,7]:   00175b18 (R) , 
                                                                                           00175b1c (R) , 
                                                                                           00175b20 (R) , 
                                                                                           00175b24 (R) , 
                                                                                           00175b28 (R) , 
                                                                                           00175b2c (R) , 
                                                                                           00175b30 (R) , 
                                                                                           00175b34 (R)   
     uint              Stack[0x58]:4  param_9
     uint              Stack[0x5c]:4  param_10
     SYS_D3D_IB_BAS    Stack[0x60]:4  param_11
     SYS_D3D_VB_BAS    Stack[0x64]:4  param_12
     FuncDef30 *       Stack[0x68]:4  param_13
     void *            Stack[0x6c]:4  param_14
     SYS_DRAW_BUFFE    Stack[0x70]:4  param_15
     undefined4        Stack[0x8]:4   local_res8                              XREF[2]:     00175b10 (W) , 
                                                                                           00175b84 (R)   
     undefined4        Stack[-0x3c]:4 local_3c                                XREF[2]:     00175aec (W) , 
                                                                                           00175b90 (R)   
     undefined4        Stack[-0x4c]:4 local_4c                                XREF[1]:     00175b7c (W)   
     undefined4        Stack[-0x50]:4 local_50                                XREF[1]:     00175b78 (W)   
     undefined4        Stack[-0x54]:4 local_54                                XREF[1]:     00175b74 (W)   
     undefined4        Stack[-0x58]:4 local_58                                XREF[1]:     00175b70 (W)   
     undefined4        Stack[-0x90]:4 local_90                                XREF[1]:     00175b14 (W)   
                     __ZN24SYS_DRAW_BATCH_RUNS_DATA3SetEPK7matrix4P  XREF[4]:     Entry Point (*) , 
                     SYS_DRAW_BATCH_RUNS_DATA_Set                                 DrawRoom_Rooms_FF_TSS:000fed58 (
                                                                                  DrawRoom_Meshes_FF_TSS:000ff168
                                                                                  SYS_DRAW_CHAR_BATCH_RUNS_DATA_SY
00175ae8 7c  08  02  a6    mfspr      r0,LR
00175aec be  21  ff  c4    stmw       r17 ,local_3c (r1)
00175af0 28  04  00  00    cmplwi     param_1 ,0x0
00175af4 7c  71  1b  78    or         r17 ,this ,this
00175af8 7c  b2  2b  78    or         r18 ,param_2 ,param_2
00175afc 7c  d3  33  78    or         r19 ,param_3 ,param_3
00175b00 7c  f4  3b  78    or         r20 ,param_4 ,param_4
00175b04 7d  15  43  78    or         r21 ,param_5 ,param_5
00175b08 7d  36  4b  78    or         r22 ,param_6 ,param_6
00175b0c 7d  57  53  78    or         r23 ,param_7 ,param_7
00175b10 90  01  00  08    stw        r0,local_res8 (r1)
00175b14 94  21  ff  70    stwu       r1,local_90 (r1)
00175b18 83  01  00  c8    lwz        r24 ,param_8.param_8 (r1)
00175b1c 83  21  00  cc    lwz        r25 ,param_8.param_9 (r1)
00175b20 83  41  00  d0    lwz        r26 ,param_8.param_10 (r1)
00175b24 83  61  00  d4    lwz        r27 ,param_8.param_11 (r1)
00175b28 83  81  00  d8    lwz        r28 ,param_8.param_12 (r1)
00175b2c 83  a1  00  dc    lwz        r29 ,param_8.param_13 (r1)
00175b30 83  c1  00  e0    lwz        r30 ,param_8.param_14 (r1)
00175b34 83  e1  00  e4    lwz        r31 ,param_8.param_15 (r1)
00175b38 41  82  00  0c    beq        LAB_00175b44
00175b3c 38  71  00  40    addi       this ,r17 ,0x40
00175b40 4b  ff  39  39    bl         matrix4_assignment                               undefined matrix4_assignment(voi
                     LAB_00175b44                                    XREF[1]:     00175b38 (j)   
00175b44 92  51  00  80    stw        r18 ,0x80 (r17 )
00175b48 7e  23  8b  78    or         this ,r17 ,r17
00175b4c 7e  64  9b  78    or         param_1 ,r19 ,r19
00175b50 7e  c5  b3  78    or         param_2 ,r22 ,r22
00175b54 92  91  00  84    stw        r20 ,0x84 (r17 )
00175b58 7e  e6  bb  78    or         param_3 ,r23 ,r23
00175b5c 7f  07  c3  78    or         param_4 ,r24 ,r24
00175b60 7f  28  cb  78    or         param_5 ,r25 ,r25
00175b64 92  b1  00  88    stw        r21 ,0x88 (r17 )
00175b68 7f  49  d3  78    or         param_6 ,r26 ,r26
00175b6c 7f  6a  db  78    or         param_7 ,r27 ,r27
00175b70 93  81  00  38    stw        r28 ,local_58 (r1)
00175b74 93  a1  00  3c    stw        r29 ,local_54 (r1)
00175b78 93  c1  00  40    stw        r30 ,local_50 (r1)
00175b7c 93  e1  00  44    stw        r31 ,local_4c (r1)
00175b80 48  00  00  19    bl         SYS_DRAW_BATCH_DATA_Set                          undefined SYS_DRAW_BATCH_DATA_Se
00175b84 80  01  00  98    lwz        r0,local_res8 (r1)
00175b88 38  21  00  90    addi       r1,r1,0x90
00175b8c 7c  08  03  a6    mtspr      LR,r0
00175b90 ba  21  ff  c4    lmw        r17 ,local_3c (r1)
00175b94 4e  80  00  20    blr
```

Which decompiles to:

```
/* SYS_DRAW_BATCH_RUNS_DATA::Set(matrix4 const*, RECTF const*, SYS_DRAW_QUALITY, SYS_DRAW_RUN
   const*, unsigned int, SYS_DRAW_MATERIAL_POOL const*, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int,
   unsigned int, SYS_D3D_IB_BASE*, SYS_D3D_VB_BASE*, void (*)(SYS_D3D_DEVICE*, SYS_DRAW_BATCH
   const&, SYS_DRAW_BATCH_RUN const&, void const*, unsigned short*), void*, SYS_DRAW_BUFFER_DEVICE* )
    */

void __thiscall
SYS_DRAW_BATCH_RUNS_DATA_Set
          (void *this,matrix4 *param_1,RECTF *param_2,SYS_DRAW_QUALITY param_3,SYS_DRAW_RUN *param _4
          ,uint param_5,SYS_DRAW_MATERIAL_POOL *param_6,uint param_7,astruct_952 param_8,
          uint param_9,uint param_10,SYS_D3D_IB_BASE *param_11,SYS_D3D_VB_BASE *param_12,
          FuncDef30 *param_13,void *param_14,SYS_DRAW_BUFFER_DEVICE *param_15)

{
  FuncDef31 *in_stack_ffffffb8;
  void *in_stack_ffffffbc;
  SYS_DRAW_BUFFER_DEVICE *in_stack_ffffffc0;
  
  if (param_1 != (matrix4 *)0x0) {
    matrix4_assignment((void *)((int)this + 0x40),param_1);
  }
  *(RECTF **)((int)this + 0x80) = param_2;
  *(SYS_DRAW_RUN **)((int)this + 0x84) = param_4;
  *(uint *)((int)this + 0x88) = param_5;
  SYS_DRAW_BATCH_DATA_Set
            (this,param_3,param_6,param_7,param_8.param_8,param_8.param_9,param_8.param_10,
             param_8.param_11,SUB3216(param_8,0),in_stack_ffffffb8,in_stack_ffffffbc,
             in_stack_ffffffc0);
  return;
}
```

Now obviously something is wrong here but I don't understand what - first of all `SUB321` expands in export to like:

`CONCAT284(CONCAT244(CONCAT204(CONCAT164(CONCAT124(CONCAT84(CONCAT44(param_8.param_8, param_5),param_6), param_8.param_9),param_8.param_10), param_8.param_11),param_8.param_12),param_8.param_13)`

And second of all those `in_stack_` shouldn't be there for sure.

Any ideas what could be the issue and how can I fix it?

I'm running a Mach-O G2 Big Endian Altivec binary.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Param 8 looks suspicious, did you maybe mean to pass a pointer or it's actually the struct?